# How to run an app in background from another application without closing the first app (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift, background, foreground

I am trying to run an app(B) in background using another app(A
) and am able to do that but app(A) is getting closed. I want the app(A) in the foreground itself and it shud run the app(B) in the background.

PS: App(B) is the normal app with all the UI functionalities in it.

Answer (score 0):

The response is NO.

You can launch another application (appB) from your application (appA) but your appA will be put in background, and appB will be in foreground. You can't just launch appB and put it in background while keep your appA in foreground.

However, if you want to use some service of appB, you have to run first appB, keep it alive in background, and run appA. Then, you can create an inter-communication between appA and appB. Take a look at: http://aplus.rs/2014/real-time-inter-app-communication/

Else, from iOS8, you can create an Extension to provide services to another application: https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions